# Order by a SQL left join on another left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to use join to fetch certain columns in 3 different tables. I made a visual representation showing how the tables are connecting in my SQL statement. I wish to order the result by `rl.level_priority` in the `role_level` table.

```
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
                user_roles ur
                ON u.id = ur.user_id LEFT JOIN
                role_level rl
                ON ur.role_level_id = rl.id AND ur.role_id = ?
                WHERE (u.id = ?) AND (u.group_id <= ?) AND (u.db_isdeleted is null)
                GROUP BY u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id
                ORDER BY rl.level_priority
```

I am struggling to see if I do this correctly. I get results, but they are not sorting ascending in regards of `rl.level_priority`

[image: Left joining a left join]

Whole code is here:

```
while($stmt_two->fetch()){
                // HIGHEST USER ROLE DISPLAYED - ACTIVE (6), LESS ACTIVE(7), PASSIVE (9)
                $db_user_group_id = 7;
                // DISPLAY USERS WITH A SET JOB POSITION
                $sql_three = <<< EOF
                SELECT u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id, MIN(rl.level_priority)
                FROM users u LEFT JOIN
                user_roles ur
                ON u.id = ur.user_id LEFT JOIN
                role_level rl
                ON ur.role_level_id = rl.id AND ur.role_id = ?
                WHERE (u.id = ?) AND (u.group_id <= ?) AND (u.db_isdeleted is null)
                GROUP BY u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id
                ORDER BY rl.level_priority;
EOF;
                $stmt_three = $mysqli->prepare($sql_three) or die ("Feil i database<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Feilmelding:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
                $stmt_three->bind_param("iii",$db_user_role_id, $db_user_group_id, $db_role_id);
                $stmt_three->execute();
                $stmt_three->store_result();
                $stmt_three->bind_result($db_id_role, $db_fullname_role, $db_image_thumb_role, $db_group_id, $db_level_priority);
                $results_users_role = $stmt_three->num_rows;
                $results += $results_users_role;

                if (!$results_users_role == 0) {
                    while($stmt_three->fetch()) {
                        $body_html .= "<tr>";
                        if (!empty($db_image_thumb_role)) {
                            $body_html .= "<td><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($db_image_thumb_role) . "\"/></td>\n";
                        }
                        else {
                            $body_html .= "<td><img src=\"img/anonymous-user-thumb.png\"></td>";
                        }

                        $body_html .= "<td><a href=user.php?u=" . $db_id_role . ">" . $db_fullname_role . "</a></td></tr>";
                    }
                }
                $stmt_three->close();
            }
```

Comment: Move ur.role_id condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (Now it executes as inner join...)

Comment: Selecting the MIN of the thing you're GROUPing BY doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Why MIN(rl.level_priority) combined with GROUP BY rl.level_priority? That's the opposite of what you want to do. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id, MIN(rl.level_priority)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_roles ur
     ON u.id = ur.user_id LEFT JOIN
     role_level rl
     ON ur.role_level_id = rl.id
WHERE (u.id = ?) AND (u.group_id <= ?) AND (u.db_isdeleted is null) AND
      ur.role_id = ?
GROUP BY rl.level_priority;
```

Your `WHERE` clause is undoing the `LEFT JOIN` (this is, turning it into an `INNER JOIN`) because `ur.role_id` will be `NULL` for non-matches.  If you really need the `LEFT JOIN`, then move this condition to an `ON` clause.

Second, you have `GROUP BY` clause, but the wrong columns there.  The correct columns are the ones *not* in aggregation functions.  Finally, you need an `ORDER BY`.

So:

```
SELECT u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id, MIN(rl.level_priority)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_roles ur
     ON u.id = ur.user_id LEFT JOIN
     role_level rl
     ON ur.role_level_id = rl.id AND ur.role_id = ?
WHERE (u.id = ?) AND (u.group_id <= ?) AND (u.db_isdeleted is null) 
GROUP BY u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id
ORDER BY rl.level_priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id, ur.role_level, MIN(rl.level_priority)
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN user_roles ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
  LEFT JOIN role_level rl ON ur.role_level_id = rl.id
WHERE ((u.id = ?) AND (u.group_id <= ?) AND (u.db_isdeleted is null)) AND
ur.role_id = ?
GROUP BY rl.level_priority
order by rl.level_priority
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY rl.level_priority when rl.level_priority is used as argument to aggregate function?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT u.id, u.fullname, u.image_thumb, u.group_id, ur.role_level, MIN(rl.level_priority)
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN user_roles ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
  LEFT JOIN role_level rl ON ur.role_level_id = rl.id
WHERE ((u.id = ?) AND (u.group_id <= ?) AND (u.db_isdeleted is null)) AND ur.role_id = ?
GROUP BY rl.level_priority
order by MIN(rl.level_priority)
```

Comment: SELECT role_id, role_name FROM roles WHERE role_name LIKE ? AND (is_deleted != 1 or is_deleted is null)
Error: Invalid use of group function